# How to write multiple statements in lambda expression body in JSP EL

Tags: jsp, lambda, el

I know we can write:

```
${
factorial = n -> n==0? 1 : n * factorial(n-1);
factorial(5)
}
```

But how do I write multiple statements in the lambda expression body in JSP EL e.g. what if I wanted to print something every time the factorial function was called? If I had a "print" function. How would I call it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write it in round braces and separate the statements by comma. The return value must be the last sub-expression. For example:

```
${
factorial = n -> (print();n==0?1:n*factorial(n-1));
factorial(5);
}
```